# ssh environment variable bash command not found

Tags: linux, variables, ssh

I try to start some command from ssh **non-interactive** ssh connection. I use ant-sshexec connection for that.

In order to set everything up I used this article:
http://www.raphink.info/2008/09/forcing-environment-in-ssh.html

I use ~/.ssh/environment.
In order to do that, I set PermitUserEnvironment to "yes" in sshd_config and restarted sshd.

In my .ssh/environment I have this content:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin

JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27

#PATH=/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin:$PATH

#PLAY_HOME=/home/ubuntu/play
```

and I have the error when try to connect using non-interactive connection:

```
 [sshexec] Could not execute the java executable, please make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set properly (the java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/java).
```

But I added the java to the path..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man page for `sshd(8)` says this about `~/.ssh/environment`:

```
    It can only contain empty lines, comment lines (that start with
    ‘#’), and assignment lines of the form name=value.
```

That is, it is not a shell script at all. You have double quotes, variable expansion and an alias definition. None of that will work. Try this:

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
JAVA_HOME=/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27
PLAY_HOME=/home/ubuntu/play
```

Also ensure that the permissions on the `~/.ssh/environment` are as described in the man page — no group or other write permissions on the file.

If you are concerned with locking yourself out of the account with a broken environment, test by logging onto the host first and running test commands such like this:

```
ssh localhost 'echo $JAVA_HOME'
```

You can ensure that the environment variables are set as you expect them and if something goes wrong, you are still logged onto the host allowing you to reverse your changes.

Comment: if I do like this I even can not login to ssh proper way at all. It says to me by entering: that all variables unavailable. Even impossible to perform command like: ls or cd. Hopefully I have several ssh connection opened, and rolled it back.

Comment: it seems it does not allow duplicate variables there as well. like PATH=... and PATH=.. but use only one PATH - at least then possible to use general commands after the edit.

Comment: @ses: Notice in my answer I do not have a duplicate path. What duplicate are you adding, and are you still expecting `$PATH` to expand inside this file?

Comment: @ses: I've expanded my answer. Does this help?

Comment: it seems this ssh localhost 'echo $JAVA_HOME' works - it shows my path..  Then I do not understand what is the problem.. At least path-related problem is fixed... trying to understand why it complains..

Comment: I created new question. sudo related problem with ssh.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080866/ssh-environment-variable-for-sudo-access  thx for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You used multiple environement variable for **path** . But don't export from command what i see.

You should do it like that way.

```
export PATH="A"
export PATH="$PATH:B"
export PATH="$PATH:C"
```

Also you can get this type of help from there.
So please post it to unix.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/how-to-run-my-c-program-from-anywhere-within-the-system-ubuntu-10-10

Hope it helps.

Comment: if I put export PATH="/home/ubuntu/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin:$PATH"
then I have: exception that it can not find Java.

Comment: -1: `~/.ssh/environment` is not a shell script. You do not export variables in it.