# ssh environment variable for sudo access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables, sudo

This question is another side of that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077259/ssh-environment-variable-bash-command-not-found/8078350#8078350)

If I want to launch some command over ssh connection, I provide ~/.ssh/environment file with variables there (but it does not allow me to use bash command there..)

But if I want to launch some command with **sudo** (like *sudo java*, for example), usually I put the following line to my **.bashrc** file

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

So, I can **NOT** put this alias into my **~/.ssh/environment** file, because it does not support any commands.

So, what it is the best way to fix it in this case?

Comment: This post may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/109474/environment-variables-over-non-interactive-ssh-connection

Comment: I guess it works but not for sudo & ubuntu.

Comment: Are you wanting a single approach that works for both sudo and ssh?

Comment: Yes. Or some workaround for this particular problem. for sudo I know the solution for ssh I know, but it does not help me for this problem. I've added new tag 'ssh' for that.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the particular problem is.  You say you want to launch some command over an ssh connection.  It seems like you want to pass a particular environment variable to the remote command.  You gave an example of how you do it with sudo, but it seems like you weren't sure about how to do it with ssh.  The link I posted talked about how to do it with ssh, but you say it doesn't work with sudo, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution.
Just remind that the issue was: **how to invoke [sudo + command] taking into account that either **sudo***  or **ssh** has some limitation to able to see environment variables.* (see above in the question).

So we may use sudo like this:

```
 sudo env PATH=$PATH command
```

It will pass PATH variable into sudo context.

It was not obvious for me that we can use something different just after sudo.. not command but env

And we can NOT use

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

in ./.ssh/environment (ssh policy limitation -  it does not allow it) and we can NOT use it in .bashrc (ssh policy limitation - it does not use it)